# How make a search by category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a two models `post` and `category` witn habtm association.How to do so would be in the query is run in `index` action in posts_controller?

Click on a category of what some, and she'll return in the same action, for sample positions in these categories.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.where(status: true)
    @categories = Category.all
  end
```

*upd*

**index.html.slim**

```
.col-md-8
  - @posts.each do |post|
    h2 = link_to post.title, post_path(post)
    = post.description
    p = sanitize post.body
.col-md-4
  - @categories.each do |category|
    h4 = link_to category.name, category_path(category)
```

Comment: sorry @weare but I didn't understand you english properly. Can you please show some more code from your view

Comment: Make category name a link, and when you click on that call index action with that category name

Answer (score 0):

```
= link_to category.name, {:controller => "controllername", :action => "index", :search=> category.name}
```

Add a search field in the form, and call the same `index` action with some string,
then in controller

```
def index
   if params[:search]
       @categories = Category.where(name: params[:search])
   else
        @posts = Post.where(status: true)
        @categories = Category.all   
   end
end
```